# How can I say "exercise"?

Tags: verbs

I am looking for this particular meaning:

> Exercise: Do physical activity in order to become stronger and healthier

The dictionary at lernu.net gives me *ekzerci*, but according to PIV it is used for many different contexts, and has a more wide definiton.

> Ekzerci: Lertigi per ripetata praktikado.

In some situations using *ekzerci* can be confusing, since it can be apprehended as *practice*.

- Vi devas ekzerci vin pli.
- Mi ekzercas min trifoje po semajno.
- Ŝi apenaŭ ekzercas sin.

Is there a more specific translation for this meaning of *to exercise*?

Comment: I usually say *sportumi* but I guess that isn’t really very specific either. It’d be interesting to know how other languages handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Oni ne cxiam bezonas nur unun vorton por traduki ion. En Esperanto, oni povas uzi *sporti/sportumi*, *trejni/trejnadi*, *ekzerci sin*, ktp, sed nenio de ili havas la saman signifon de la angla *to exercise*.

Do, se vi sentas vin ke iu ne vere komprenas, simple klarigu per aldoni pli da vortojn.

Ekzemple:
"Mi planos levi pezojn" / "Cxiutage ni trejnadas gimnazie"

Cxiam estas metodo por plene esprimi vin mem.

Comment: En Esperanto, "gimnazio" estas speco de mezlernejo kaj ne povas nomi sportejon. Por la angla "gym" oni povas diri ekzemple "sporthalo" aŭ "gimnastikejo". Se vi intencas "gym" en la senco de "fitness centre", eblas diri "korpotrejnejo"

Answer (score 0):

Uzu adverbon por precizigi vian verbon, ekzemple "plibonsancele ekzerci" (pli-bon-san-cel-e)